# Lazy Load to route other than empty route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, router

I have my `app-routing.module.ts` as follow:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {
        Routes,
        RouterModule
    } from '@angular/router';

    const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path        : 'reset', 
            loadChildren: 'app/auth/reset-password-form/reset-password-form.module#ResetPasswordFormModule'
        },
        {
            path        : 'verify',
            loadChildren: 'app/auth/verify-user-form/verify-user-form.module#VerifyUserFormModule'
        },
        {
            path        : '404',
            loadChildren: 'app/route-not-found/route-not-found.module#RouteNotFoundModule'
        },
        {
            path        : '',
            pathMatch   : 'full',
            loadChildren: 'app/landing-page/landing-page.module#LandingPageModule'
        },
        {
            path      : '**',
            redirectTo: '/404'
        },

    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    }
```

When I navigate to the `localhost:4200`, it will load the `landing-page.module` properly, however, when I entered `localhost:4200/reset` or `localhost:4200/verify` or `localhost:4200/404`, it will not load the relevant module, instead, it loaded `landing-page.module` automatically.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Still have the problem? Your problem is the order of routes, in first place you must set the '' path, in the last place you must set the '**'

Comment: I have a similar problem where lazy loaded route goes to a different lazy   loaded module...I get equivalent to your "verify" module being mistakenly loaded in response to "reset" path

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Routes to your childmodule

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ResetComponent}
  ];
  const ROUTES: ModuleWithProviders = 
  RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

and import ROUTES in child module(ResetModule)

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ROUTES,
    ],
 declarations: [ResetComponent],
 exports: [ResetComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem might happen because of the imports you have added in `imports:[ ]` of `AppModule` (or any other module file).

Make sure to remove all the lazily loaded modules from the imports array.

for eg: I have three modules named:`HomeModule`, `ProfileModule` and `SettingsModule`.
if `HomeModule` is eagarly loaded and `ProfileModule` and `SettingsModule` are lazily loaded, then `imports:[]` of `AppModule(app.module.ts)` should look like this:

`imports:[HomeModule]` and it shouldn't include `ProfileModule` or `SettingsModule` because they will be loaded automatically during runtime.